# Fix a firmware bug for Lubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

How to fix this firmware bug:

> tsc deadline disabled due to errata please update microcode to version
>   0x52 (or later)

I'm using VirtualBox to install the image. 
My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7920HQ CPU @ 3.10GHz.

Comment: What are trying to install exactly and how?

Comment: You can just ignore it. Things install just fine despite that message. See 1 min 19 sec into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udP7zlm0--M

Comment: And please do not post duplicated questions.

Comment: I'm trying to install ubuntu on my macbook with virtual box 5.2 but it crash....